# Take out string from "<string>" in Lua

Tags: string, parsing, lua, lua-patterns

I want to parse some data from a string in Lua. I have tried several combination of `string.match` and `string.sub` but no luck. Here is the detail...

```
str='[{id:78749,name:Hrithik Roshan,character:Vijay Deenanath Chauhan,order:0,cast_id:1,profile_path:/1uGhDRNCA9I4WvyD9TfgKYnLEhZ.jpg},{id:77234,name:Priyanka Chopra,character:Kaali Gawde,ord'

fixstr = string.gsub(str,"name:","<actors>")
fixstr = string.gsub(fixstr,"character:","<actors>")
print(fixstr)
fixstr1 = string.match( fixstr, "<actors>(.+)<actors>")
print(fixstr1)
```

Output:

Output of  `rint(fixstr)`

```
[{id:78749,<actors>Hrithik Roshan,<actors>Vijay Deenanath Chauhan,order:0,cast_id:1,profile_path:/1uGhDRNCA9I4WvyD9TfgKYnLEhZ.jpg},{id:77234,<actors>Priyanka Chopra,<actors>Kaali Gawde,ord
```

Output of  `print(fixstr1)`

```
Hrithik Roshan,<actors>Vijay Deenanath Chauhan,order:0,cast_id:1,profile_path:/1uGhDRNCA9I4WvyD9TfgKYnLEhZ.jpg},{id:77234,<actors>Priyanka Chopra,
```

What I am trying to do is get all the string between `<actors>...<actors>`
but it didn't worked. Can anybody help on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all the strings between `<actors>` and `<actors>`, use `string.gmatch` for global match:

```
for name in string.gmatch(fixstr, "<actors>(.-)<actors>") do
    print(name)
end
```

Note the use of `.-` in which `-` matches zero or more occurrences, but it's non-greedy.

Output:

```
Hrithik Roshan,
Priyanka Chopra,
```

---

Actually, unless you need `fixstr` for other uses, you don't need to substitute `name:` and `character:` to `<actors>`, just one run of `string.gmatch` can do the job:

```
for name in string.gmatch(str, "name:(.-)character:") do
    print(name)
end
```

Comment: Thanks it worked like charm. But becouse its in loop it will give output in new line every time it runs i want it in single string like .....Hrithik Roshan,Priyanka Chopra,Sanjay Dutt,Rishi Kapoor,Zarina Wahab,Om Puri,

Comment: @user1640175 The new line is added by `print`. You can initialize an empty string `result = ""` and concatenate the names to it in the loop `result = result .. name`.

Comment: @user1640175, you can also use `io.write(name,' ')` instead of `print`.